# MvvmCross - 4.0 Beta 3 doesn't work with new UWP project?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, uwp

I started a new Windows 10 UWP project today and used Nuget to add references for the beta version of MvvmCross. After adding references to MvvmCross and some HotTuna plugins (like StarterPack), all I get is the following:

[image]

I seem to be missing some stuff because I'm unable to inherit from MvxStorePage. Also, when I added HotTune to my Android project, a ToDo.txt file was added with instructions, but in the UWA project, I didn't get any of those extra files.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The files where not added because that is no longer allowed in Nuget 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can inherit from MvxStorePage, because it doesn't exist in the namespace available to UWP project.

In UWP project, the `Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsUWP` namespace is used. You can check it in Visual Studio in "Class View (Ctrl + Shift + C)". And the only available view is MvxWindowsPage as below.

[image]

Based on the [Universal Windows App tutorial](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Tip-Calc-A-Universal-Windows-App-UI-Project) on GitHub, the MvxWindowsPage is recommended to be used in universal app. Note that, the tutorial is for Universal Windows app for 8.1, but it's same to make it work in a win10 UWP app. Just change the namespace from `Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsCommon.Views` to `Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views`. By doing that, I didn't get any problem to inherit from MvxWindowsPage.